# Riddle: which is the next bigger number?

Tags: puzzle

How to solve this puzzle?
[Follow this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spGjk.jpg)

Comment: this more suits to http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @prakharlondhe Alright, thanks.

Comment: See [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subsequent smallest value of $x$ is $1680$.

We need $x$ such that
$$x+1 = m^2 \text{ and }x/2+1 = n^2$$
Eliminating $x$, we need $m$ and $n$ such that
$$m^2 + 1 = 2n^2 \text{ or }m^2-2n^2=-1$$
This is an example of Pell's equation, see [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j75cgoahb8f0etd/lecture_15.pdf?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwn2fhgrts0cao3/lecture_16.pdf?dl=0). The approach is to guess the smallest positive solution, which in this case is $(n_1,m_1)=(1,1)$. All the remaining solutions are given by the Brahmagupta's identity, i.e.,
$$(m_{k+1},n_{k+1}) = (3m_k+4n_k,2m_k+3n_k)$$
This gives us that $(m_2,n_2) = (7,5)$, i.e., $x=7^2-1 = 48$.

Next, we obtain $(m_3,n_3) = (3\cdot7+4\cdot5,2\cdot7+3\cdot5) = (41,29)$, which gives us that $x=41^2-1 = 1680$.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest i could get was $1680$. ($1681=41^2, 841=29^2$).